# How do you send data to a web socket using curl?

Tags: bash, shell-script, curl, socket

I'm using a bash shell and tryhin gto communicate with a web socket. 
 I found this script -- https://gist.github.com/htp/fbce19069187ec1cc486b594104f01d0 that is supposed to connect to a web socket, but it doesn't list the parameters if you actually need to pass along data to the endpoint.  How is that done?

If curl is not up to the task I'm open to anther command line tool.  THe point is not to use curl, but to see stuff in action from the comamnd line.

Comment: There are some useful answers in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47860689/how-to-read-websocket-response-in-bash

Comment: Neither of these answers submits data when connecting to teh web socket and one of them uses curl.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 7):

The script you've found only sends the headers needed to establish the initial Websockets handshake. And you also need to actually show you the headers from the response and understand these to determine if the handshake was successful. But apart from being usable to test the initial handshake curl has no support for Websockets, i.e. it is impossible to actually exchange data using Websockets with curl.

Comment: Is there another command line tool that does this?  I will edit my question b/c I'm not married to curl.

Comment: @Dave: A simply search for [command line tool websocket](https://www.google.com/search?q=command+line+tool+websocket) provides you with several tools.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer...

Answer (score 7):

I suggest you to use my new tool [websocat](https://github.com/vi/websocat).

```
echo "Some data to be sent" | websocat ws://server/url
```

Obviously, there are also alternatives like [wscat (golang)](https://github.com/emulbreh/wscat) or [wscat (node)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wscat).